# How to reference an Avro union type with nested logical type

Tags: java, maven, avro

Given a schema field that is a union type where one of the union types is a logical type:

```
{
  "name": "price",
  "type": [
    "null",
    {
      "type": "bytes",
      "logicalType": "decimal",
      "precision": 8,
      "scale": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

How should this be referenced in the produced message?

```
"price": {
  "bytes": "\u0000È"
}
```

OR

```
"price": {
  "bytes.decimal": "\u0000È"
}
```

I cannot seem to find any supporting documentation of what should be expected in this case. Based on my own tinkering in Java code, I have only been able to correctly read the data using a `SpecificDatumReader` (org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.3) when the message has `bytes` and not `bytes.decimal`.
I do not want to assume that just because it works with the Java library that it is correct. Any supporting documentation or examples would be greatly appreciated.

For extra context, I am using `avro-maven-plugin` with a version of `1.11.3` to generate the record. I have specified `<enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>` in the plugin and it works as expected.